# Is there an "enhanced" numpy/scipy dot method?

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy

#### Problem

I would like to compute the following using numpy or scipy:

```
Y = A**T * Q * A
```

where `A` is a `m x n` matrix, `A**T` is the transpose of `A` and `Q` is an `m x m` diagonal matrix.

Since `Q` is a diagonal matrix I store only its diagonal elements as a vector.

#### Ways of solving for `Y`

Currently I can think of two ways of how to calculate `Y`:

1. `Y = np.dot(np.dot(A.T, np.diag(Q)), A)` and
2. `Y = np.dot(A.T * Q, A)`.

Clearly option 2 is better than option 1 since no real matrix has to be created with `diag(Q)` (if this is what numpy really does...)
However, both methods suffer from the defect of having to allocate more memory than there really is necessary since `A.T * Q` and `np.dot(A.T, np.diag(Q))` have to be stored along with `A` in order to calculate `Y`.

#### Question

Is there a method in numpy/scipy that would eliminate the unnecessary allocation of extra memory where you would only pass two matrices `A` and `B` (in my case `B` is `A.T`) and a weighting vector `Q` along with it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

(w/r/t the last sentence of the OP: i am *not* aware of such a numpy/scipy method but w/r/t the Question in the OP Title (i.e., improving NumPy dot performance) what's below should be of some help. In other words, my answer is directed to improving performance of most of the *steps comprising* your function for Y).

First, this should give you a noticeable boost over the vanilla NumPy ***dot*** method:

```
>>> from scipy.linalg import blas as FB
>>> vx = FB.dgemm(alpha=1., a=v1, b=v2, trans_b=True)
```

Note that the two arrays, v1, v2 are *both* in C_FORTRAN order

You can access the byte order of a NumPy array through an array's ***flags*** attribute like so:

```
>>> c = NP.ones((4, 3))
>>> c.flags
      C_CONTIGUOUS : True          # refers to C-contiguous order
      F_CONTIGUOUS : False         # fortran-contiguous
      OWNDATA : True
      MASKNA : False
      OWNMASKNA : False
      WRITEABLE : True
      ALIGNED : True
      UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

to change the order of one of the arrays so both are aligned, just call the NumPy array constructor, pass in the array and set the appropriate *order* flag to True

```
>>> c = NP.array(c, order="F")

>>> c.flags
      C_CONTIGUOUS : False
      F_CONTIGUOUS : True
      OWNDATA : True
      MASKNA : False
      OWNMASKNA : False
      WRITEABLE : True
      ALIGNED : True
      UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

You can further optimize by exploiting array-order alignment to *reduce excess memory consumption caused by **copying** the original arrays*.

But why are the arrays copied before being passed to *dot*?

The dot product relies on BLAS operations. These operations require arrays stored in C-contiguous order--it's this constraint that causes the arrays to be copied.

On the other hand, the *transpose* does *not* effect a copy, though unfortunately returns the result in *Fortran order*:

Therefore, to remove the performance bottleneck, you need to *eliminate the predicate array-copying step*; to do that just requires passing both arrays to *dot* in C-contiguous order*.

So to calculate **dot(A.T., A)** *without* making an extra copy:

```
>>> import scipy.linalg.blas as FB
>>> vx = FB.dgemm(alpha=1.0, a=A.T, b=A.T, trans_b=True)
```

In sum, the expression just above (along with the predicate import statement) can substitute for dot, to supply the same functionality but better performance

you can bind that expression to a function like so:

```
>>> super_dot = lambda v, w: FB.dgemm(alpha=1., a=v.T, b=w.T, trans_b=True)
```

Comment: This is really a nice way of accessing the BLAS routines. I'm sure I can make good use of it in the future. 
However, there still remains a `Q` to be inserted here somewhere... :)

Comment: sure, i should have prefaced my answer above with "i do not know of such a numpy/scipy method as you describe in the *last* sentence of the OP, *but* here's how to improve performance of most of the steps comprising your function for Y; apologies if that was misleading (my answer edited accordingly).

Comment: @doug What about speed? In my test dgemm seems to be much slower than np.dot no matter what order my matrices are. Should dgemm be faster than numpy.dot?

Comment: Could you explain what does 'trans_b=True' mean? The reference does not have detailed description about this.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to put that up on SO, but this pull request should be helpful and remove the need for a separate function for numpy.dot
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/2730
This should be available in numpy 1.7

In the meantime, I used the example above to write a function that can replace numpy dot, whatever the order of your arrays are, and make the right call to fblas.dgemm.
http://pastebin.com/M8TfbURi

Hope this helps,

Comment: would you have any examples of when np.dot (in numpy 1.8) does / does not copy an arg ? Or, how can I tell ?

Answer (score 2):

**numpy.einsum** is what you're looking for:

```
numpy.einsum('ij, i, ik -> jk', A, Q, A)
```

This shall not need any additional memory (though usually einsum works slowlier than BLAS operations)