# Why does X.dot(X.T) require so much memory in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

X is a n x p matrix where p is much larger than n. Let's say n = 1000 and p = 500000. When I run:

```
X = np.random.randn(1000,500000)
S = X.dot(X.T)
```

Performing this operation ends up taking a great deal of memory despite the result being of size 1000 x 1000. The memory use goes back down once the operation is finished. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Interesting. Aside from the space for `X` and `S` this should be doable in very little, constant space: Take a transposed view of `X`, calculate and allocate the space for `S`, and calculate each element of `S` directly. And from the little I know about NumPy, something similar should fall out automatically from this composition of operations...

Comment: I am not sure of the details, but whenever possible numpy tries to use BLAS routines, which I think would be [`sgemm`](http://www.math.utah.edu/software/lapack/lapack-blas/sgemm.html) for matrix multiplication. My bet is that these highly optimized routines require contiguous data (probably in Fortran order), and thus a copy has to be made in your case.

Comment: Use numpy >=1.8, that will help with many of such cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is not that `X` and `X.T` are views of the same memory space *per se*,
but rather that `X.T` is F-contiguous rather than C-contiguous. Of course, this must
necessarily be true for at least one of the input arrays in the case
where you're multiplying an array with a view of its transpose.

In numpy < 1.8, `np.dot` will
create a C-ordered copy of *any* F-ordered input arrays, not just ones that happen to be views onto the same block of
memory.

For example:

```
X = np.random.randn(1000,50000)
Y = np.random.randn(50000, 100)

# X and Y are both C-order, no copy
%memit np.dot(X, Y)
# maximum of 1: 485.554688 MB per loop

# make X Fortran order and Y C-order, now the larger array (X) gets
# copied
X = np.asfortranarray(X)
%memit np.dot(X, Y)
# maximum of 1: 867.070312 MB per loop

# make X C-order and  Y Fortran order, now the smaller array (Y) gets
# copied
X = np.ascontiguousarray(X)
Y = np.asfortranarray(Y)
%memit np.dot(X, Y)
# maximum of 1: 523.792969 MB per loop

# make both of them F-ordered, both get copied!
X = np.asfortranarray(X)
%memit np.dot(X, Y)
# maximum of 1: 905.093750 MB per loop
```

**If copying is a problem (e.g. when `X` is very large), what can you do about it?**

The best option would probably be to upgrade to a newer version of numpy - as @perimosocordiae points out, this performance issue was addressed in [this pull request](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/2730).

If for whatever reason you can't upgrade numpy, there is also a trick that allows you  to perform fast, BLAS-based dot products without forcing a copy by calling the relevant BLAS function directly through `scipy.linalg.blas` (shamelessly stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9479621/1461210)):

```
from scipy.linalg import blas
X = np.random.randn(1000,50000)

%memit res1 = np.dot(X, X.T)
# maximum of 1: 845.367188 MB per loop

%memit res2 = blas.dgemm(alpha=1., a=X.T, b=X.T, trans_a=True)
# maximum of 1: 471.656250 MB per loop

print np.all(res1 == res2)
# True
```

Comment: It's mentioned above, but numpy >=1.8 solves this problem for you: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/2730

Comment: @perimosocordiae Yep, but some people might find it awkward to upgrade for whatever reason (broken dependencies etc.), so I thought I'd give a solution using 1.7.1. I'll edit my answer to make that clearer.